# Sign app with JDK7 keystore

Tags: java, android, keytool, sign, jarsigner

I generated a keystore file using the `keytool` included with JDK 7, signed my app with it and uploaded it to the Google Play Store for beta testing.

My beta testers are getting a "Error - Package file was not signed correctly" error, which I believe is because JDK 7's jarsigner uses a different algorithm?

I have switched to the JDK 6 `jarsigner` and passed in the `-sigalg SHA1withRSA` and `-digestalg SHA1` switches to set the algorithm that Android requires.

However, my beta testers are still getting the same error. My question is: Can you use the JDK 6 jarsigner tool with a `keystore` file created with the JDK 7 `keytool`?

I would just generate a new keystore with the JDK 6 keytool, but I don't want have to re-create my Google Play listing if at all possible..

Comment: Signing JAR file with jarsigner is explicitly not the same as [signing APK](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html), although the same keystore can be used.

Comment: Think I was just too hasty. Seems like beta testers can install it fine now. Ensuring that I was using Java 6 and passing in those alg switches solved it. Interestingly, I couldn't replicate the error - perhaps because my device is rooted?